# Can Excel auto generate squencial number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a manual invoice registry log which I would like to overhaul.

Currently I will manual assign an invoice number when I want to create a new invoice. Let's say Column A is the Invoice Number and Column B is Company Name.

Invoice Number format will look like EPS-I-S150901. "EPS-I-S" is fixed, I will use either "EPS-I-S"&... or change the number format to "EPS-I-S"000000.

The remaining 6 number digits will be more tricky. 15=Year, 09=Month and last 2 digits= Sequential Numbers. When we reach Oct, it will auto change to 10 and the last 2 digits will reset back to 1 and start all over again until the next month.

The Company Name will just be in text format, like ABC Inc.

After my first manual entry, is it possible for cell A2 to auto generate a new sequenced invoice number upon any  new company name entry on cell B2?

It looks more favourable to use Access in this case rather than Excel but I do not have Access with me.

Comment: what is the format of your invoice number? What should be the rule for the generation of new one? What have you tried so far? Please don't answer with a comment, but edit your question.

Comment: The answer is yes, it's possible to auto-generate a new sequence number when a new company name is entered.  If you want something more specific than that, you will need to describe exactly what you want the results to look like so that people can help.

Comment: Invoice Number format will be EPS-I-S150901. "EPS-I-S" is fixed, I will use either &"EPS-I-S" or change the number format to "EPS-I-S"000000. The rest 6 number digits will be more tricky. 15=Year, 09=Month and Last 2 digits= Sequential Numbers. When we reach Oct, it will auto change to 10 and last 2 digits will reset back to 1 and start all over again until the next month.

Comment: The Company Name will just be in text format, like ABC Inc. Hence whenever I enter a new company name, it will recognise this as a new line entry and auto generate an invoice no for me. It looks more favourable to use access in this case rather than excel but i do not have Access with me.

Comment: @Brandon: Include all explanation within the question (that's where people will look for it, and the edit will refresh your question in the active questions list).  If you "address" your comment like I did this one, the person will receive an alert.  Otherwise, nobody will be aware of your posting unless they stumble across it.

Comment: I can't focus on your problem at the moment, but I can get you started.  I suspect you may need VBA.  You can create the next Serial No, and hide it if there is no Co name, with something like: =IF(ISBLANK(B2),"","EPS-I-S"&RIGHT(YEAR(TODAY()),2)&TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()),"00")&TEXT(IF(TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()),"00")=MID(A1,10,2),VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2))+1,1),"00")).  However, TODAY() will update each day, so you would need to pre-populate the formula down Col A.  When you enter a Co Name, copy & paste special, value in the A cell to lock in the result.  You could use VBA to automate the whole thing.